# Silverlight 3 DataGrid SelectionChanged event fired when switching applications

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, selectionchanged

This is annoying...When running my SL3 app with a datagrid after having selected a row in the grid, if I alt-tab to a different application and then alt-tab back - the SelectionChanged event fires!  No click or touch was done to the SL app.
What I'm trying to do is allow the user to click on a row to mark it Read/Unread but I guess I'm going to have to add a checkbox to the row to handle this since the automatic event firing behavior is getting in the way.  I should not have to dance around with GotFocus/LostFocus to handle this.
Any ideas?
thanks